# Field over over $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

I know that a vector space $V$ over $\mathbb{F}$ is when the elements in each entries in any vector in $V$ is an element in $\mathbb{F}$

But what do people mean when they say,

Let $\mathbb{F}$ be a field over $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Where did you hear/see that?

Comment: It's on an assignment about inner product space

Comment: Sounds like a mistake.   Probably meant to say vector space

Answer (score 0):

Saying that $\mathbb{F}$ is a "field over $\mathbb{R}$" means that $\mathbb{F}$ is a field containing $\mathbb{R}$ as a subfield.

Comment: I've never seen this use of the terminology. Do you know of a reference which uses it in this way?

Comment: So $\mathbb{C}$ would be an example in this case then?

Comment: @MichaelAlbanese The [Stacks Project](http://stacks.math.columbia.edu/download/fields.pdf) uses the phrase "field over another field", and Google also found various things, like the terms "function field over" (in a paper of Poonen) and "splitting field over".

Comment: @interdelta Yes.